# Temperature Control on and Induction Cooktop

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering

Many induction cooktops for sale have the option of controlling the temperature instead of setting the heat.  How does the temperature control typically work?  Is it an open loop or closed loop control system?  Is the temperature measured using an infrared sensor, or by some other means?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a survey of technologies used in consumer goods is outside of the scope of the site. If you can focus your question on a specific, practical problem, please [edit] accordingly.